# How to get elements whose title attribute value matches a supplied string while combining preceding filters

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to fin elements that have title attribute whose value matches a case insensitive string that I supply. ie. matches regardless of whether they're the same case.

When I try the following it works:

```
$(".head[title*='premier' i]").length
```

But when I want to combine with more filters, I get an error:

```
$(".itemSport").eq(0).find(".groupMenu:contains(England)")
.find(".head[title*='premier' i]").length
```

Which is the best way to get elements whose title attribute matches a supplied string while combining my other preceding filters?

Edit: link to page I'm querying:

https://web.betin.co.ke/Sport/Groups.aspx?IDSport=20&Antepost=0

I want to find elements that contain 'Premier' under the first soccer button (somtimes,the case changes that's why I need the query to be case agnostic):

```
<div class="head" ng-click="openEvent()" title="Premier League">
                                    <span class="nameEvent ng-binding" ng-bind="itemEvent.Evento">Premier League</span>
                                    <span class="eventCount ng-binding" ng-bind="itemEvent.NumSottoeventi">20</span>
                                </div>
```

Comment: That returns 0 elements but if I use uppercase P for premier I get a number of elements returned

Comment: But yes, the error is gone. Just not returning the elements. I want it to search for elements with title attribute matching premier regardless of case

Comment: Actually, your code assumes I want the <i> element which is not the case

Comment: What exactly do you expect `$(".itemSport").eq(0).find(".groupMenu:contains(England)").find(".head[title*='premier' i]").length` to match?

Comment: @asemahle edited the question to specify

Comment: @RandyCasburn If I remove the `I` it won't be case insensitive. I need it case insensitive. How can I do this?

Comment: @RandyCasburn: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors#Links

Comment: Not sure why your query doesn't work... It might be a JQuery bug with the `.find` method. This should work `$(".itemSport").eq(0).find(".groupMenu:contains(England)").find( $(".head[title*='premier' i]") ).length`. Basically avoid using a CSS selector in the `.find` method, and pass it a list of elements instead.

Comment: Well that's a nifty little trick. Thanks. Add as answer for me to accept.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure why your query doesn't work. It might be a JQuery bug with the `.find` method.

To get around it use this:

```
$(".itemSport")
    .eq(0)
    .find(".groupMenu:contains(England)")
    .find( $(".head[title*='premier' i]") )
    .length
```

Basically avoid using a CSS selector in the `.find` method, and pass it a list of elements instead.